# Setting ID for "n" buttons

Tags: javascript

```
    //Display
        for (var z=0; z<n; z++) {   
            document.write("<tr><td>"+ z + "</td>");  // Serial
            document.write("<td>" + RandonValue + "</td>"); // Random Number
            document.write('<td><button onclick="reply_click()" id="button-' + z + '">Click me</button></td></tr>'); //onClick
        }

    //Set ID
    function reply_click(clicked_id){
        alert(clicked_id);

    }
```

Somehow I got `undefined` for all of them.

The `replay_click` is only for checking, I want to change that when I have different IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you. Check it. I hope it fulfills the requirements :)

https://jsbin.com/doxusi/edit?html,js,output

```
<table id="mytable"></table>

var html = '';
  var random = 5;
  for (var i = 1; i <= random; i++) {
    html += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + i + '</td>' +
      '<td>Some Number</td>' +
      '<td><button id="id_' + i + '">Button ' + i + '</button></tr></td>';

  }

  document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML = (html);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your z variable is the counter in this case which you can use for your id, keep in mind you can't have an ID starting with a number.

```
document.write('<td><button onclick="somefunction" id="button-' + z + '">Click me</button></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your `z` variable like this, also putting double quotes (best practice:

```
document.write('<td><button onclick="somefunction(this)" id="mycell-' + z + '">Click me</button></td></tr>');
```

Note that you better pass `this` to your function, so inside that function you can reference that id:

```
function somefunction(elem) {
    alert('you clicked ' + elem.id);
}
```

Comment: That worked.. but i got undefined.. i change the qeustion

Comment: That is because you did not do as I said: pass `this` to your function... But I see you already accepted another answer.